Split date range into new records for each month in Snowflake (with datetimes instead of dates)
I pretty much want to achieve the same as this: Split date range into new records for each month in Snowflake View
Except my dataset consists of datetimes and not dates. I want to preserve these timestamps and split the date ranges into months but keep the time stamps so as to be able later to perform time difference calculations.
I tried using the solution provided by @Pankaj in the other discussion and change dates into datetimes but it doesn't work and I'm a bit stuck. I am new to SQL and data in general so please pardon my lack of knowledge and/or poor description of the issue.

Please update your question with sample data and the result you wanted to achieve - both formatted as tables so they are readable. Please also update your question with the SQL you've managed to write and explain how it doesn't work (error messages, wrong result, etc)
